# Particle swarm optimization and function with several parameters

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, particle-swarm

I would like to optimize a function with several parameters using Particle swarm optimization. How can i do it? Everywhere I found this formula 1, but how can I understand this formula, I can optimize a function with only one variable. For example, I have a function with 2 parameters and I want to maximize it. How can I do it with PSO?

> vi,d ← ω vi,d + φp rp (pi,d-xi,d) + φg rg (gd-xi,d)

```
function (x, y)
{
    return x + y
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you have just 2 variable to optimize, your search space would be two dimensional. Assume that you want to optimize parameters x1 and x2. Furthermore, x1 is in the range of [a1,b1] and x2 is in the range of [a2,b2]. First you need to initialize a random population of particles (say 30 particles) into the search space boundary and assign random values to velocity vectors (V). Afterwards, you need to evaluate the fitness of the all particles and determine the best particle (Global best). Then you should perform the main upading mechanism of PSO.
This link would be helpful:
http://yarpiz.com/50/ypea102-particle-swarm-optimization